# Endless Pivot Control

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to use a `Pivot` control for a calendar type app, where each `Pivot` view shows some infos about the current day. When the user swipes forward, the next day is shown. I implemented this by adding items to the end of the `Pivot` Item collection, which works fine.

My problem occurs when the user tries to go backward to the previous day. In this case a new item is added at the beginning of the `Pivot` item collection. Although the adding works, the shown Pivot item is always the wrong one (ie. the newly added item). Setting `SelectedItem` on the `Pivot` control doesn't help.

I think `Pivot` might not be the right control for my task, so any help about what view to use or how fix my aforementioned problem with `Pivot` are highly appreciated.

code for my Viewmodel that implements going forward/backward one day.
`Pages` is bound to the Pivot `ItemSource`.

```
public class TrackDayViewModel : HubViewModelBase
{
    private DateTime _CurrentDay;
    public DateTime CurrentDay
    {
        get { return _CurrentDay; }
        set
        {
            if (value.CompareTo (_CurrentDay) != 0)
            {
                _CurrentDay = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentDay");
            }
        }
    }

    public TrackDayViewModel ()
    {
        var day = DateTime.Now;

        CurrentDay = day.Midnight();

        Pages.Add(new DayViewModel(CurrentDay.AddDays(-1)));
        Pages.Add(new DayViewModel(CurrentDay));
        Pages.Add(new DayViewModel(CurrentDay.AddDays(1)));

        SelectedItem = Pages[1];

        this.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedItem")
            {
                var si = SelectedItem as DayViewModel;

                if (si != null)
                {
                    var idx = Pages.IndexOf(SelectedItem);
                    if (idx==0)
                    {
                        Pages.Insert(0, new DayViewModel(si.Day.AddDays(-1)));
                        SelectedItem = Pages[1];
                    }
                    else if (idx == (Pages.Count - 1))
                    {
                        Pages.Add(new DayViewModel(si.Day.AddDays(1)));
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

EDIT: Change that solved my problem:

```
        this.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedItem")
            {
                var si = SelectedItem as DayViewModel;

                if (si != null)
                {
                    var idx = Pages.IndexOf(SelectedItem);

                    int nextIdx = (idx + 1) % 3;
                    int prevIdx = ((idx - 1)<0)  ? 2 : (idx-1);

                    Pages[nextIdx] = new DayViewModel(si.Day.AddDays(1));
                    Pages[prevIdx] = new DayViewModel(si.Day.AddDays(-1));
                }
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, I'd use a Pivot control with 4 pages.

At any one time, the previous, current and next pages will contain correct data - and you will always have one (empty) page

You can then respond to the events when your current page is changing and has changed - use these events to set up the current (empty) page to the correct new content and to then clear the new (empty) page.

Comment: thanks, your answer pointed me to the right direction, I edited my question with the code I used

Answer (score 1):

The guidelines for Pivot control state that it should be avoided if you have more than 6 pages.

Using it for unlimited pages in out of question.

What I would recommend is using `TransitioningContentControl` with help of touch gestures for flipping forward and backward. `TransitioningContentControl` allows you to use animation while its content is being changed.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I know that my solution it is kind of a misuse of Pivot, but it seems to work.