# How to create a smooth move on WP7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am working on project which loads large images on WP7, divides them on smaller pieces(size about 480x680) and pictures them piece by piece. I need to create smooth move between these parts of images and I don´t know how. I have one Image element which has size same as a display of WP7 emulator - I am loading single image piece into this element and don´t know how to solve the possibility of the smooth move onto the neighbouring image.

Any ideas?

Comment: ditto. +1 on the gnarley title. awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for

- if you are looking for DeepZoom type functionality then check out this sample http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/03/28/deep-zoom-on-wp7.aspx
- if you are more interested in smooth scrolling between photos then check out the TransitioningContentControl  in the Toolkit - with Gestures added, then this might work for you (see the answer in [Endless Pivot Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146960/endless-pivot-control))

Comment: Pivot would be fine, but I need to allow users to move in all direction between pieces of image (not even left and right) You can imagine that I have large image divided into 9 pieces. Piece in the center is pictured on display and I need to allow users to move onto piece in top left corner of that large image

Comment: sounds like deepzoom is what you want

Comment: It´s a project to school and I think that I can´t use something like that, besides I had implemented the picture separation (I am dividing large image and then I am saving them as separate JPG images). Only 1 thing I need is something like Pivot but with possibility to move up and down - is there something like that?