# Windows phone 8 apps - Image swiping

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have to Swipe the images in windows phone 8 apps without any `Panorama` or `Pivot control`.

I am using the `Flick` event for the swiping images. Images changing perfectly. But animation is not applied which means swiping animation is not coming.

Please suggest us.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible solutions, depending on the 'what' animation you want to see.
But a good solution can be found [here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146960/endless-pivot-control)

The principle is easy, create a pivot control but manipulate it's content by plugging in into the pivot events.